# score_mode:total in elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I am having a little bit of trouble with a `custom_filters_score`. Individual scores `0.81491333`, `0.125` and `0.08695652` are added up to equal `0.1727262`…

**EDIT**: I looked over it again and it looks like the total of the custom_filters_score is being multiplied by the 'normal' query.

Is there a way to either incorporate the normal query (`custom_score`) into the `custom_filter_score` or, alternatively, a way to force elasticsearch to add the two together (instead of multiplying)?

A gist of the data, query and mapping is at https://gist.github.com/sqwk/3d7b25192a236fba82b4

Comment: What version of ES are you using? I see some commits to fix score explanations in recent versions

Comment: `0.20.6` I looked over it again and it looks like the total of the custom_filters_score is being multiplied by the 'normal' query. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: Ah, that's score normalization, and the same value is applied to all results of a query - you can ignore it. And no you can't disable it without writing some custom Java

Comment: I mean, is there a way to add the two together instead of having them multiplied? Custom java is fine, just need to know where to put it ;)

Comment: Can you gist a full recreation, with mapping, data, query, as curl statements? I'd like to understand exactly what is happening

Comment: @drtech data, mapping and query are gisted at https://gist.github.com/sqwk/3d7b25192a236fba82b4

Comment: The link that contained all the data is not working anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I've finally figured out what is happening.  First, in your gist, your query doesn't match any of your documents, because of the lat/lon. I chose one document at random (323) and use the lat/lon values from there.

This is the explanation I get:

```
 - custom score, score mode [total]                                    |    0.8795
   - Score based on score mode Max and child doc range from 10 to 16   |    1.0000
     - Child[16]                                                       |    1.0000
   - custom score, product of:                                         |    0.2000
     - match filter: cache(object_max_rooms:[4 TO *])                  |    1.0000
     - scriptFactor                                                    |    0.2000
     - queryBoost                                                      |    1.0000
   - custom score, product of:                                         |    0.5714
     - match filter: cache(object_min_living_area:[* TO 125])          |    1.0000
     - scriptFactor                                                    |    0.5714
     - queryBoost                                                      |    1.0000
   - custom score, product of:                                         |    0.1081
     - match filter: cache(object_max_living_area:[125 TO *])          |    1.0000
     - scriptFactor                                                    |    0.1081
     - queryBoost                                                      |    1.0000
```

As you can see, the lat/lon matches exactly, so scores 1, and the scores from the `custom_filters_score` query are being totalled up nicely.

Then I changed the `lat` value from 50.0852386 to 50.0882386, and reran. Now the scores look like this:

```
 - custom score, score mode [total]                                    |    0.7081
   - Score based on score mode Max and child doc range from 10 to 16   |    0.8050
     - Child[16]                                                       |    0.8050
   - custom score, product of:                                         |    0.2000
     - match filter: cache(object_max_rooms:[4 TO *])                  |    1.0000
     - scriptFactor                                                    |    0.2000
     - queryBoost                                                      |    1.0000
   - custom score, product of:                                         |    0.5714
     - match filter: cache(object_min_living_area:[* TO 125])          |    1.0000
     - scriptFactor                                                    |    0.5714
     - queryBoost                                                      |    1.0000
   - custom score, product of:                                         |    0.1081
     - match filter: cache(object_max_living_area:[125 TO *])          |    1.0000
     - scriptFactor                                                    |    0.1081
     - queryBoost                                                      |    1.0000
```

So the score from the filters is being combined with the score from the query, and then normalized.  This is to be expected.  The `score_mode` only applies to the filters, not the combination of the filters and the query.

If you want to combine them exactly, then you would need to move the distance calculation out of the query into a filter under the `custom_filters_score` filters. The problem there is that the `script` for scoring won't have access to the nested `places` docs, so you would be unable to do that.

Why is the exact total so important? The `_score` should never be taken as an absolute value. It just reflects the relative importance of each document.  You just need to tweak the impact of each clause until you're getting the "right" order for your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to test this. The exact total is not really important, yet a multiplication doesn't work, because then one component of getting the right order depends on another.
Is there a way to loop over nested fields using mvel? (If I move the query into the filter under the `custom_filters_score` I'd need to do the calculations in a single script.)

Comment: No, unfortunately. Nested docs are separate docs internally. The doc in context is the root doc.  It can't see the nested docs.  You *could* use `_source['..']` instead of `_doc['...']` to get hold of the lat/lon values, but that will be considerably slower.